# How do you get the MessageID from AWS SES when using SMTP using C#

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, smtp, amazon-ses, mailkit

I am putting this question out there because it took me the better part of two days figuring this out by putting answers together.

I was attempting to receive AWS's MessageID that it assigns to an email so that I could later use SNS/SQS to receive email feedback. And using System.Net.SmtpClient responded with a void for successful emails. You only received exception codes on a failure.

AWS will always send a response, but to get the message on success I needed to incorporate MailKit nuget and use the MessageSent event.

The resposne looks like this....   "OK xxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxx" where x's are the newly assigned messageID.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the simplest code to send an email with the method I used to get the messageID from the successful response. I hope this saves people a lot of time!

Simply use MailKit nuget and the following code:

```
using MailKit.Net.Smtp;
using MailKit.Security;
using MimeKit;

namespace TestMail
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            await SendMail();
        }

        internal static async Task SendMail()
        {
            using (var mail = new MimeMessage())
            {
                mail.From.Add(MailboxAddress.Parse("from@email.com"));

                mail.To.Add(MailboxAddress.Parse("to@email.com"));

                mail.Subject = "TEST";

                mail.Body = new TextPart(MimeKit.Text.TextFormat.Html) { Text = "<P>Hello!</P>" };

                string goodMessage = "";
                using (var smtp = new SmtpClient())
                {
                    smtp.MessageSent += async (sender, args) =>
                    {
                        goodMessage = args.Response;
                    };
                    
                    await smtp.ConnectAsync("email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com", 587, SecureSocketOptions.StartTls);

                    await smtp.AuthenticateAsync("user", "password");
                    await smtp.SendAsync(mail);                                    
                }

                Console.WriteLine("This is the messageID: " + goodMessage.Split(' ')[1]);

            }            
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that starting with MailKit 3.0, the Send() and SendAsync() methods now return a string value so that you don't actually need to listen to the MessageSent event:

```
using (var smtp = new SmtpClient())
{
    await smtp.ConnectAsync("email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com", 587, SecureSocketOptions.StartTls);
    await smtp.AuthenticateAsync("user", "password");

    string response = await smtp.SendAsync(mail);
    string[] tokens = response.Split(' ');
    string id = tokens[1];

    await smtp.DisconnectAsync(true);
}
```

Comment: Do you need to disconnect when smtp is inside a using?

Comment: You don’t “have” to, but the Dispose() method just closes the socket rather than sending the QUIT command to the server, which is considered nicer etiquette.